# Identify Shapes in Selection in order

Tags: excel, shapes, vba

Let's say that I've selected two or more shapes in an Excel tab using the mouse.

Is there a VBA command(s) to determine the shape names in the sequence in which they were selected?

**Selection.count** only returns the number of shapes in the selection.

Recording the macro during the shapes selection process yields

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Shape_A")).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Shape_A", "Shape_B")).Select
```

What I need is the reverse, wherein I extract the names from the selection for use in a VBA macro.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through them by using `.ShapeRange`:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Shape_A")).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Shape_A", "Shape_B")).Select

For Each myshape In Selection.ShapeRange
    Debug.Print myshape.Name
Next myshape
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks!